# How to apply deduplication for an array returned in Zapier Code output

Tags: zapier

I have a Zapier Code block that does `fetch` for JSON array and the preprocess this data. I cannot use Zapier Webhook with polling, because I need to process the data a bit.

Zapier Webhook offers deduplication feature, by having `id` parameter associated with the items returned in an array from the URL endpoint. How can I achieve the same for Zapier Code? Currently, my zap is trying to process and trigger on the same data twice. This leads to the error that Zapier tries to send out the same tweet twice, every time the Code is triggered.

Here is mock data returned by my Code:

```js
output = [{id: 1, name: "foo"}, {id: 2, name: "bar"}]
```

Currently, without deduplication, I am getting this email and having my zap disabled:

> Your Zap named XXX was just stopped. This happened because our systems detected this Zap posted a duplicate tweet, which is against Twitter's Terms Of Service.

Comment: I am trying to see if StoreClient could act as a storage for deduplication, but StoreClient limitations seem to be pretty low - only 500 keys or deduplications https://zapier.com/help/create/code-webhooks/store-data-from-code-steps-with-storeclient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use storage by Zapier to achieve this. the ideal flow will be :

1. Trigger
2. Storage by Zapier [Get Value (use storage key = `lastItemId`) ]
3. Code By Zapier (Filter array return only those record that has `id` greater than the `lastItemId`)
4. Storage By Zapier (Set Value) : update `lastItemId` with the last item processed by Code By Zapier step

---

You can also use StoreClient in place of the Storage By zapier, but always update a existing key `lastItemId` and compare id of the record with ```lastItemId`` and at the end update StoreCLient key (lastItemId)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer from Kishor Patidar, here is my code. I am adding the example code, here is too some time to figure it out. Specifically, in my case, the items cannot be processed in the order of appearance (no running counter primary keys) and also there are some limitations how far in the future Zapier can schedule actions (you can delay only up to one month).

The store also has a limitation of 500 keys.

[image]

```js
// We need store for deduplication
// https://zapier.com/help/create/code-webhooks/store-data-from-code-steps-with-storeclient
// https://www.uuidgenerator.net/
var store = StoreClient('xxx');

// Where do we get our JSON data
const url = "https://xxx";

// Call FB public backend to get scheduled battles
const resp = await fetch(url);
const data = await resp.json();

let processed = [];


for(let entry of data.entries) {
    
  console.log("Processing entry", entry.id);

  // Filter out events with a non-wanted prize type
  if(entry.prizes[0].type != "mytype") {
    continue;
  }
  
  // Zapier can only delay tweets for one month
  // As the code fires every 30 minutes, 
  // we are only interested scheduling tweets that happen
  // very soon
  const when = Date.parse(entry.startDate);
  const now = Date.now();
  
  if(!when) {
     throw new Error("startDate missing");
  }
  
  if(when > now + 24 * 3600 * 1000) {
    // Milliseconds not going to happen for next 24h
    console.log("Too soon to schedule", entry.id, entry.startDate, now);
    continue;
  } else {
    console.log("Starting to schedule", entry.id, entry.startDate, now);
  }
  
  const key = "myprefix_" + entry.id;
  
  // Do manual deduplication
  // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64893057/how-to-apply-deduplication-for-an-array-returned-in-zapier-code-output
  const existing = await store.get(key);
  if(existing) {
      // Already processed
    console.log("Entry already processed", entry.id);
    continue;
  }  
  
  // Calculate some parameters on entry based on nested arrays
  // and such
    
  entry.startTimeFormat = "HH:mm";
 
  // Generate URL for the tweet
  entry.signUpURL = `https://xxx/${entry.id}`;
  processed.push(entry);
  
  // Do not tweet this entry twice,
  // by setting a marker flag for it in store
  await store.set(key, "deduplicated");

}

output = processed;
```